# Python sockets stealing each other's packets

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm trying to write a program to test data transfer speeds for various-sized packets in parallel. I noticed something odd, though, that the size of the packet seemed to have no effect on transfer time according to my program, whereas the Unix `ping` binary would time out on some of the packet sizes I'm using. I was sending 4 packets containing the string 'testquest' and one that was just 2000 bytes set to 0. However, when I printed the results, they *all* contained 'testquest' (and were far shorter than 2000 bytes). The only thing I can conclude is that these sockets are somehow all receiving the same packet, which would explain how they all had the same rtt.

I made this MCVE to illustrate the issue (you can ignore the 'checksum' function, it's included for completeness but I know from experience that it works):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import socket
import struct
import time
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
from sys import argv, byteorder

def calculate_checksum(pkt):
    """
    Implementation of the "Internet Checksum" specified in RFC 1071 (https://tools.ieft.org/html/rfc1071)
    Ideally this would act on the string as a series of 16-bit ints (host
    packed), but this works.
    Network data is big-endian, hosts are typically little-endian,
    which makes this much more tedious than it needs to be.
    """

    countTo = len(pkt) // 2 * 2
    total, count = 0, 0

    # Handle bytes in pairs (decoding as short ints)
    loByte, hiByte = 0, 0
    while count < countTo:
        if (byteorder == "little"):
            loByte = pkt[count]
            hiByte = pkt[count + 1]
        else:
            loByte = pkt[count + 1]
            hiByte = pkt[count]
        total += hiByte * 256 + loByte
        count += 2

    # Handle last byte if applicable (odd-number of bytes)
    # Endianness should be irrelevant in this case
    if countTo < len(pkt): # Check for odd length
        total += pkt[len(pkt) - 1]

    total &= 0xffffffff # Truncate sum to 32 bits (a variance from ping.c, which
                        # uses signed ints, but overflow is unlikely in ping)

    total = (total >> 16) + (total & 0xffff)    # Add high 16 bits to low 16 bits
    total += (total >> 16)                      # Add carry from above (if any)

    return socket.htons((~total) & 0xffff)

def ping(args):
    sock, payload = args[0], args[1]
    header = struct.pack("!BBH", 8, 0, 0)
    checksum = calculate_checksum(header+payload)
    header = struct.pack("!BBH", 8, 0, checksum)

    timestamp = time.time()
    sock.send(header+payload)

    try:
        response = sock.recv(20+len(payload))
    except socket.timeout:
        return 0

    return (len(response), (time.time() - timestamp) * 1000)


host = argv[1] # A host that doesn't respond to ping packets > 1500B

# 1 is ICMP protocol number
sockets = [socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, proto=1) for i in range(12)]

for i, sock in enumerate(sockets):
    sock.settimeout(0.1)
    sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", i))
    sock.connect((host, 1)) # Port number should never matter for ICMP

args = [(sockets[i], bytes(2**i)) for i in range(12)]

for arg in args:
    print(ping(arg))
    arg[0].close()
```

This actually shows me something more troubling - it seems that the rtt is actually *decreasing* with increasing packet size! Calling this program (as root, to get socket permissions) outputs:

```
0
0
(24, 15.784025192260742)
(28, 0.04601478576660156)
(28, 0.025033950805664062)
(28, 0.033855438232421875)
(28, 0.03528594970703125)
(28, 0.04887580871582031)
(28, 0.05316734313964844)
(28, 0.03790855407714844)
(28, 0.0209808349609375)
(28, 0.024080276489257812)
```

but now notice what happens when I try to send a packet of size 2048 using `ping`:

```
user@mycomputer ~/src/connvitals $ time ping -c1 -s2048 $box
PING <hostname redacted> (<IP address redacted>): 2048 data bytes

--- <hostname redacted> ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss

real  0m11.018s
user  0m0.005s
sys   0m0.008s
```

Not only is the packet dropped, but it takes 11 seconds to do so! So why - if my timeout is set to 100ms - is this packet getting a "successful" response from my python script in only ~0.04ms??

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

## Update:

I just checked again, and it seems that it's multiple sockets that are the problem, and the threading seems to have nothing to do with it. I get the same issue when I ping with each socket - then immediately close it - sequentially.

Comment: The times are too small to be considered significant. Your ICMP packets seem to be missing part of the ICMP header, so the all have the same ID and sequence number (0). Thus the replies are indistinguishable. So the first reply is seen by every socket and causes all the sockets to receive the packet and return.

Comment: I omitted the id and sequence fields because I assumed that each socket would represent a separate connection, and since each connection only sends one packet there was no need to distinguish sequence and id. If that's not the case, are you saying that a socket will somehow only consume packets with the same identifier it sent? Because since I'm constructing these packets from the ground up for a raw socket, I don't see how that's possible; I could easily send multiple identifiers from the same socket.

Comment: There is no "connection" information in your SOCK_RAW icmp packets. By using that API you've agreed that you will implement all the demultiplexing logic behind "connections" however you define them. ICMP provides space in the header for identifiers, but you have to implement the logic to use them on transmission and receipt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your sockets are identical, and all bound to the same host.  There simply isn't any information in the packet for the kernel to know which socket to go to, and [raw(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/raw.7.html) seems to imply all sockets will receive them.

You're probably getting all the responses in all the threads, meaning you're getting 12 times as many responses per thread as you're expecting.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean the responses are still consumed, even if I can't tell which socket consumes them? And if that's the case, some of them should still timeout.

Comment: It is possible (maybe likely, going off the man page) that it is going to all sockets, meaning you are getting 12 times as many packets as you'd expect, so enough packets for everyone.  I will amend my answer.

Comment: I tried binding each to a different port on `0.0.0.0`, but it didn't work - same issue. Does there need to be only one socket listening on a single address at a time? If so, I don't know how possible it is to do threaded pinging of a remote host...

Comment: ICMP (itself) doesn't have ports.  You would have to put something in the packet to distinguish them, and discard the ones that aren't relevant.  This is conventionally what the Identifier and Sequence number fields are for, in the data section.

Comment: Each thread's socket is only listening for one packet, and then ping returns

Comment: Then if I'm going to try to do this concurrently, I must need a global timeout to stop listening for packets, and just see how many come back in that time period. Which is annoying, because I never know how big of a packet to expect.

Comment: Ah, indeed, still, depending on thread ordering, each thread will probably still receive a duplicate packet.

Comment: You could just send all the packets on one socket, with a data field, and then wait for the replies.  There's no real reason to do it fully concurrently.

Comment: No, that's what I mean. I'll use one socket to send multiple packets, but then I need to wait for packets which may or may not be coming and are of unknown size, then also do processing on them to figure out which packets -if any- were lost. It's a lot more annoying than if sockets worked the way I thought, and it'll also hold up the rest of the program, which I want to check routing information, udp pings and other stuff which would all require different sockets connecting to the same host.